# Accessing cmake build path outside of cmake

Tags: python, c++, cmake, scripting

I would like to build multiple C++ executables with cmake and then use a python script to link them into a different directory.

Is there a way to make the path to the cmake build directory outside of cmake?

Comment: You do specify the build directory during the cmake configuration. You should be able to use this info in whatever logic you're running the python code from. If it can be anywhere on the file system and you don't have any info available where the build directory recides, you're screwed anyways. Even searching the whole file system there's no way of finding the build directory, since there could be multiple build dirs per project. You need to explain what you mean by *"ink them into a different directory"* though...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Basically the executables require some configuration files and process a bunch of data that are stored in a folder provided by the end user. The executables run in sequence. The end user provides this case directory to the python script and it should link the executables into that directory from where they were built using cmake.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your problem, but I think an end user should never link to binaries inside the build directory. Even if you know the source location, the build path could be anywhere (e.g. by using cmake presets).

Is it an option to install your binaries properly and then use that target folder for linking the executables?

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm not knowledgeable enough about cmake. What happens is the following: Let's say I'm on the command line and have cloned my repository. Then I am inside the repository. I create a folder `build` and go there: `mkdir build; cd build`. Then I run cmake and build the executables: `cmake ..; make`. The finished executables will be located in the `build/` directory. Then I will enter a work directory and use the Python script to create a case folder: `cd ../work/; script.py "case name"`. `script.py` links the executables from `build/` to `work/case/`.